# Is it possible to auto-translate contents in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-translate, looker-studio

I've created a report of FB ads shared between stakeholders from different countries. One of the components is the Ad Body which are in many languages and I want the viewers from different countries to understand what's the other countries're talking about on the ad by, ideally, switching from local language to English and vice versa.

Is there any way, or connector, that can help translate the content directly on GDS report? something like Google Translate is fine. Thanks.